# Why was Amara feared in Agrabah?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, once-upon-a-time-in-wonderland

The [*Once Upon A Time Wiki*](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Amara) says the following about Amara:

> Later, Amara becomes a widely feared sorceress who lives on the outskirts of Agrabah, and retains her affinity for serpents. The city's inhabitants are terrified of her, to the point the locals evacuate the market whenever she comes to do her shopping.

Why was Amara so feared and what did she do to make herself so widely known amongst Agrabah that they would hide from her?

Answer (score 3):

### Aside from fairies, saviors, and genies, virtually everyone who uses magic is evil

There are four main groups of people who use magic in the *Once* universe:

- Fairies
- Saviors
- Genies
- Everybody else

Fairies don't seem to come to Agrabah. The main show reveals that a Savior did come through Agrabah, but they weren't recognized as such. Genies are subservient to their master and can't really be considered good or evil.

That leaves everybody else, and virtually all of them are evil. We have The Dark One, several evil queens (Regina, Anastasia, Maleficent, etc), and other assorted evil magic users (Jafar, the Wicked Witch). As we are told ad nauseum, "All magic comes with a price." That price for most people is evilness.

There are a few exceptions like the Mad Hatter or the Apprentice who aren't evil (and Elsa, who <s>was shoehorned into the story for a cash grab</s> lives in a realm isolated from everything else), but they seem to be content to sit on the sidelines and not get involved. Those who do get involved are invariably evil.

Bringing it back to Agrabah, the people haven't seen any of the good magic users come through and, if they've heard of any magic users from different realms, it's almost certainly one of the evil ones. So odds are that Amara is evil too.

Plus there's just the general fear of what she is capable of. This is a person who prefers to live alone and has the power to turn you into a snake. Do you really want to risk coming to her?

In the absence of further information about her past, that's about the best information we can come up with about why she was feared.